# Incorrect set options on SQL Server + Laravel

Tags: sql-server, laravel

I'm facing the following problem:

When running an insert instruction the system raises the following error:

> INSERT failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'ANSI_NULLS, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, ANSI_WARNINGS, ANSI_PADDING'

This errors happens only on the production server. If I make the same query on my development machine running on the exact same database, there is no error. This happened so far in only one table, other tables accept insert statements properly.

Development machine:

- Running Windows 10 + Xampp
- Apache 2.4.37
- PHP 7.3.0
- Laravel 5.7.19
- sqlsrv 5.5.0-preview+11607 (extension php_sqlsrv_73_ts.so)

Production server Machine

- Centos 7.6.1810
- Apache 2.4.6
- PHP 7.3.3
- Laravel 5.7.19
- sqlsrv 5.6.0+11812 (extension php_sqlsrv_73_nts.so)

Database server machine

- Windows 2008R2
- SQL Server 2014 Express

Any ideas why this happens only when running the query on the production server? Since the database is the same and when querying other tables I get no error, what could be possibly wrong with this particular table?

Regards

Comment: Man, it's 2021 and I'm still getting that error. Shame on you, sql server!